# Access a specific object from an array of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a variable which returns an object. This object has multiple properties, the first property is an array of more objects. I want to access this one by one using javascript and render it using html css and js.

This is my object variable (myObj).

```
const myJson = item.message;
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJson);
console.log(myObj);
```

In the first image you can see the returned object that has 2 properties.

In the second image I have expanded the first property which itself is an array of objects.

[First image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxOpO.png)
[Second image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A4jBp.png)

1. I want to access these objects one by one and print them in tables using HTML, CSS and JS
2. I want to access object property based on each property index rather than its property name
   eg: all the object keys will be table headers and all its values will be in data cells.
   I know if I want to do this without using property name eg: obj.id I have to use for loops, but I can't seem to get this correctly. Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow! Please take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding about how to [ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Afterwards, please [edit] your question to add *all* the relevant code.

Comment: Order of properties is not that reliable.  I suggest you make an array of property names in the correct order, and use that to iterate the objects.

Comment: you can use 2 `for` loops, first one to loop through the array of objects, and second one to loop through properties. as suggested in the comments you can create an array of property names, and use for your second loop and print it easily.

Comment: @MeBottleOScrumpy okay so for the object myObj this returns an object with 2 properties. I want to access courseconfig. This is an array with 50+ objects, after this I can loop through again to access each object. I tried using myObj[0] to access the first property but couldnt.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what i understood from the question.

```js
const data = {courseconfig:[{title:'title1', id:'id1'}]};

for(let i = 0; i < data.courseconfig.length; i++){
  
  const objectKeys = Object.keys(data.courseconfig[i]);
  
  for(let j = 0; j < objectKeys.length; j++)
    console.log(data.courseconfig[i][objectKeys[j]]);

}
```

EDIT 1: to access a property of an object which has a name you can use '.name', or ['name'].

EDIT 2: New snippet added

```js
function extractInfo(someArray){

  for(let i = 0; i < someArray.length; i++){
  
    const objectKeys = Object.keys(someArray[i]);
  
    for(let j = 0; j < objectKeys.length; j++)
      console.log(someArray[i][objectKeys[j]]);

  }
}

const data = {courseconfig:[{title:'title1', id:'id1'}], filterconfig:[{ title:'title2', id:'id2' }]};

const dataKeys = Object.keys(data);

for(let i = 0; i < dataKeys.length; i++){
  
  if(Array.isArray(data[dataKeys[i]])){
    extractInfo(data[dataKeys[i]]);
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, just one question, is it possible to instead of using courseconfig to access that based on its index instead of typing courseconfig? because there are mulitple ones like that, userconfig, enrolconfig and so on, this would mean I would have to type it out each time. So instead data.courseconfig.length, I would like to use index

Comment: if you mean something like the second `for` loop then yes. it can be done

Comment: const data = {courseconfig:[{title:'title1', id:'id1'}]}; in your example you've done it this way right. 
Suppose this is the case: { courseconfig: [ { title : 'title1', id : 'id2' } ], filterconfig:[{ title:'title1', id:'id1' }] };  So my object variable : myObj returns :
{courseconfig: Array(52), filterconfig: Array(21) }

I want to access courseconfig like you have done, but I want to access it using index, so how can I achieve it this way. So how in arrays we use array[0] to access first element, same way is it possible to access this?

Comment: @user19080871 edited answer might solve it.